# Grunt Build creates broken app

Tags: angularjs, build, gruntjs, yeoman

I've made an AngularJS web application using Yeoman as project starter.

Launching the following command:

```
grunt serve
```

everything is working fine.

If I try to test the dist version for production, using the following command:

```
grunt serve:dist
```

I get erorrs like this in browser console:

```
    vendor.f13d432c.js:1 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uuid4 due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'uuid4' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

What's wrong?

EDIT

Same happens with:

```
grunt build
```

and then deploy the dist folder in a webserver

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

```
npm install
```

Apparently, 'uuid4' is missing. This is a npm package so chances are you still need to include this, running npm install.

Comment: Just tried to run that command, but nothing has changed. The strange thing is that not minified version is correctly working (`grunt serve`), but dist version not (`grunt serve:dist`).